# Electric field due to a time and space varying current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, superposition

Let us say I have a current density:
$$\vec J\equiv\vec  J(\vec r, t)$$
This will produce both a time varying magnetic field and a net charge density. Both these effects produce an electric field. If $\vec E_B$ is the electric field considering only the time varying magnetic field and $\vec E_{cd}$ is the electric field considering only the net charge density can we say in general:
$$\vec E=\vec E_B+\vec E_{cd}$$
If so can it be proven and if not why not?

Comment: You need to solve Maxwell's equations to find the electric field. Maxwell's equations are a set of coupled differential equations and in general you cannot say which source produces what. You need to solve the equations simultaneously. Here, the charge density gives rise to an electric field which in turn is coupled to a magnetic field and so on. If you decouple the equations you get this wave equation for the E field:
$$\left (\nabla ^2 -\mu \epsilon \dfrac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}\right ) \mathbf E= \mu \dfrac{\partial \mathbf J}{\partial t} +\dfrac{\nabla \rho}{\epsilon}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment:
Consider the Maxwell equations:

$$\nabla \cdot {\bf E}=\rho/\epsilon_0 \qquad \nabla \cdot {\bf B}=0$$
$$\nabla\times {\bf E}=-\dfrac{\partial {\bf B}}{\partial t} \qquad\nabla\times {\bf B}=\mu_0 {\bf J}+\dfrac{1}{c^2}\dfrac{\partial {\bf E}}{\partial t}$$

According to [Heras](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/76/6/10.1119/1.2899735) (when commenting on a paper by [Griffiths and Heald](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/59/2/10.1119/1.16589)) the displacement current term $\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial {\bf E}}{\partial t}$ can be written in terms of the current density ${\bf J}$ as

$$\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial {\bf E}}{\partial t} = \frac{{\bf J}}{3} + \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int d^3x'[{\bf F}({\bf J})]$$

where ${\bf F}({\bf J})$ depends upon ${\bf J}, \frac{\partial {\bf J}}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial^2 {\bf J}}{\partial t^2}$ and denotes quantities at the retarded time [*I'm assuming it's OK to make use of Helmholtz, since although the rhs of the expression for $\nabla \times {\bf B}$ involves time, it does not involve time derivatives of* ${\bf B}$ *in which case you'd have to make use of the following [generalisation](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/58/2/10.1119/1.16225) of Helmholtz's Theorem*]. Because of this, this means that we know $\nabla \cdot {\bf B}$ and $\nabla \times {\bf B}$. From Helmhotlz's Theorem this means we can write ${\bf B}$ in the form ${\bf B} = \nabla \Phi + \nabla \times {\bf A}$ and $\Phi, {\bf A}$ are determined uniquely. This gives ${\bf B}$ determined by the current density ${\bf J} (and it's time derivatives)$.

This now means we have $\nabla \cdot {\bf E}$ given in terms of the charge density and $\nabla \times {\bf E}$ given in terms of the time derivative of ${\bf B}$ (which is given in terms of the time derivative of the current density ${\bf J}$). It follows that since we know the divergence of ${\bf E}$ and the curl of ${\bf E}$ we can write ${\bf E}$ in terms of the gradient of some scalar function $\Phi'$ and the curl of a vector function ${\bf A'}$ as ${\bf E} = \nabla \Phi'+ \nabla \times {\bf A'}$, and it is seen that $\Phi'$ is related to the charge density while ${\bf A'}$ is related to the (time derivative) of the magnetic field.